# Magento: Removed content block from layout but still visible on landing page

Tags: magento, layout

I am a new Magento developer working with Magento 1.7. I have read the Designer's Guide and consequently attempted to remove the product comparison content block from my right sidebar. I commented this block out in /blank_template/layout/catalog.xml (where 'blank_template' is the name of the new blank template I have enabled in admin). Please see the code snippet below.

```
<!--
Default layout, loads most of the pages
-->

    <default>

        <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
        <reference name="top.menu">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.topnav" template="catalog/navigation/top.phtml"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="core/template" name="left.permanent.callout" template="callouts/left_col.phtml">
                <action method="setImgSrc"><src>images/media/col_left_callout.jpg</src></action>
                <action method="setImgAlt" translate="alt" module="catalog"><alt>Our customer service is available 24/7. Call us at (800) DEMO-NUMBER.</alt></action>
                <action method="setLinkUrl"><url>checkout/cart</url></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="right">
        <!--
            <block type="core/template" before="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/template" name="right.permanent.callout" template="callouts/right_col.phtml"/>
        --> 
            <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="footer_links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalog" ifconfig="catalog/seo/site_map"><label>Site Map</label><url helper="catalog/map/getCategoryUrl" /><title>Site Map</title></action>
        </reference>

    </default>
```

I don't understand why it is that the product comparison block is still visible on my landing page? You can view the landing page here: http://rewards.duxter.net. I have disabled all Magento caches. According to the template path hints, this is the correct file to modify. Can anyone please explain why my code is not working? Thank you so much!

Comment: do you have a local.xml layout file in the same dir? Check that to make sure it's not being overridden.

Comment: @sulman I checked, and did not find any local.xml layout file in /blank_template/layout.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the cache has been disabled, head into var/cache and delete any existing directories. We regularly experience similar weirdness Magento caching behavior on our dev and beta sites (both of which have caching disabled).